# Setting custom date in DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

Is there possibility to set a custom date in DatePicker? 
I want to set a date in DatePicker, and then allow user to edit it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/04/android-date-and-time-controls.html) tutorial? It says to set the DatePicker initially, use DatePicker.init:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
dp.init(cal.getTime().getYear()+1900, cal.getTime().getMonth(), cal.getTime().getDay(), this);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the [DatePicker.init](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29) where you can set it...

Or to set the date you can use the calendar control as shown in the [android developer sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html).  See Steps 4-6.

[Here's another sample blog post on this](http://sree.cc/google/android/setting-custom-date-in-android-date-picker).

Answer (score 0):

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

Comment: How is it different from Jack's answer?