# Get a particular date from server on datePicker dialog android

Tags: android, date, datepicker

Hi I am trying to set a particular date(from server) on date picker dialog when the first time user opens the dialog. After that the date will be set dynamically. But I am not able to get that date on the date picker. It always shows the current min date. Is there any easy way to fix this?

```
 //My date from server

         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           long l = Long.parseLong(posttime);
                   cal.setTimeInMillis(l);
                   int dmonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int dday = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int dyear= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
           dateTextView.setText(dday+" " + dmonth + " " +dyear);

        //Date to be set dynamically

         Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
         DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    PostInfoUpdate.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1
            );

        dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
                now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
                dpd.setMaxDate(now);


       //To open the dialog
              public void show() {
            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");

                }

      //To set the date 
            @Override
       public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
         String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
          dateTextView.setText(date);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the current time to be set dont do it ;)

```
        dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
            dpd.setMaxDate(now);
```

define your own "time" (from server or static) and set this

EDIT:

```
 @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            date_picker_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, get_date, year, month - 1, date);
            return date_picker_dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310750/how-to-set-a-specific-date-in-date-picker-in-android You can use the method from answer 1 to set the datepicker onstart to your desired date. The code I "quoted" sets the date to the current date (now). I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this  dpd.initialize(mCallBack, dyear, dmonth, dday); and I got my date but now I can't change the date.

Comment: I added a code snipped that I found here. Sorry I dont have the ressources here to test it. But maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert a custom date, when you got your date from server split it into "year"-"month"-"day" and insert them into this method

```
    public dinamicDate(int year, int month, int day){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        Context,
                        year,
                        month,
                        day;
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
    }
```

then you just call it

```
    dinamicDate(year, month, day);
```