# change datepicker dialog current date - android java

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

Can I change the day highlight (circled in red). This is displaying the systems current day but my app works in a different timezone so how can I un-highlight the day or change it to another day.

[image]

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    billDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            billDateDialog.show();
            billDateDialog.updateDate(billDateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), billDateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), billDateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
    });


    billDateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            // Bills need to be set to 00.00 hours. DST needs to be ignored because changing to other timezones with no DST will cause problems with days changing to the day before.
            long correctedTime = new DayLightSavings(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, timeZone).getCorrectedTime();
            billDateCal.setTimeInMillis(correctedTime);
            billDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(billDateCal.getTimeInMillis()));
        }

    },billDateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), billDateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), billDateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    // Do not allow selection of <= today's date.
    // TODO Dialogue needs to be based on timezone selection.
    long oneDay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    long oldRawOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    long newRawOffset = timeZone.getRawOffset();
    long rawOffset = oldRawOffset - newRawOffset;
    // TODO fix dialogue to display the correct timezone current day.
    billDateDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + oneDay - rawOffset);
}
```

Comment: What is the current good app time ?

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310750/how-to-set-a-specific-date-in-date-picker-in-android

Comment: the good app time is the 14th

Comment: @Mazz any solution for this?

Comment: no unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is before showing your dialog initializing the dialog with the app good date. This code is comming from an android app.

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) billDateDialog.getDatePicker();
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);

DateTime apptime = DateTime.now() ; //From your app, db or other 
int y    = apptime.getYear() ;
int m   = apptime.getMonthOfYear() - 1;      // Need to subtract 1 here.
int d     = apptime.getDayOfMonth();  
int h    = apptime.getHourOfDay();
int min = apptime.getMinuteOfHour();

//setters
datePicker.updateDate(y, m, d);            
timePicker.setCurrentHour(h);                    
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(min);
```

Comment: This only updates the selected date, not the highlighted date circled in red